# Thread was being aborted exception in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Code is :

```
Response.Redirect("~/Admin/uploadMaterials.aspx",false);
```

After this redirect line is executing page is loading, not redirecting to `uploadMaterials.aspx`

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> > Redirect calls End which raises a ThreadAbortException exception upon completion.

You should catch and ignore the `ThreadAbortException`, and then your redirect should work:

```
try
{
    // Code that calls Response.Redirect
}
catch (ThreadAbortException)
{
    // Do nothing
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // Handle other exceptions
}
```

Comment: I have try this also, still page is not redirecting it just loading loading

Comment: @user3529113 Well in that case I think you're going to need to show us more than one line of code. Can you show us more of this page's code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use server.transfer instead (or use the Response.redirect(....,true) to quit running the current page code and go to the next - but I have had a few GPF as a result.